# Load layout outside magento with translation

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, localisation

i have to load magento in a cms and want to include the complete header. Everything works fine, but i don't get the right translation of the template. The locale setting of the store view is correct.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('de');

$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('default')->load();
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

echo $layout->getBlock('header')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to emulate the store:

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId); 
//your code here
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

The code between start/stopEnvironmentEmulation should just work as within Magento.

The cool thing is, that `startEnvironmentEmulation()` also takes care of the locale with the following line from `Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation`:

```
$initialLocaleCode = $this->_emulateLocale($storeId, $area);
```

Otherwise you can just try to emulate the locale like this:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($storeId());
```